# почему скорость умножения матриц при параллельном умножении на много медленнее чем обычное умножение

Tags: java

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

public class ParallelMultiplicationMatrix implements Runnable {
    private int i;
    private int j;
    private double result = 0;
    private double firstMatrix[][];
    private double secondMatrix[][];
    private double resultMatrix[][];
    private double Row[];
    private double Column[];

    public double[] getRow(int i, double firstMatrix[][]) {

        Row = new double[firstMatrix.length];

        for (int j = 0; j < firstMatrix.length; j++) {
            Row[j] = firstMatrix[i][j];
        }

        return Row;

    }

    public double[] getColumn(int i, double secondMatrix[][]) {

        Column = new double[secondMatrix.length];

        for (int j = 0; j < secondMatrix.length; j++) {
            Column[j] = secondMatrix[j][i];
        }

        return Column;

    }

    ParallelMultiplicationMatrix(int i, int j, double firstMatrix[][], double secondMatrix[][], double[][] ResultMatrix) {
        this.i = i;
        this.j = j;
        this.firstMatrix = firstMatrix;
        this.secondMatrix = secondMatrix;
        this.resultMatrix = ResultMatrix;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        int sizeOfMatrix = resultMatrix.length;
        double[] row = getRow(i, firstMatrix);
        double[] column = getColumn(j, secondMatrix);
        for (int k = 0; k < sizeOfMatrix; k++) {
            this.result += row[k] * column[k];
        }
        resultMatrix[i][j] = this.result;

    }

    static double[][] generateMatrix(int size) {
        double[][] randomMatrix = new double[size][size];
        for (int k = 0; k < size; k++) {
            for (int l = 0; l < size; l++) {
                randomMatrix[k][l] = (int) (new Random().nextFloat() * 100);
            }
        }
        return randomMatrix;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int size = 1000;
        double[][] firstMatrix = generateMatrix(size);
        double[][] secondMatrix = generateMatrix(size);
        double[][] resultMatrix = new double[size][size];
        List<Thread> threads = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < resultMatrix.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < resultMatrix.length; j++) {
                Thread thread = new Thread(new ParallelMultiplicationMatrix(i, j, firstMatrix, secondMatrix, resultMatrix));
                threads.add(thread);
            }
        }


        for (Thread thread : threads) {
            thread.start();
        }
        try {
            for (Thread thread : threads) {
                thread.join();
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {

        }
        System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(resultMatrix));

    }
}
```

Comment: Намного это на сколько?

Comment: ... и что такое "обычное умножение"?

Comment: на минут восемь

Comment: обычное - не используя потоки

Comment: Да потому что при матрице 1000*1000 Вы создаете МИЛЛИОН потоков!!! Вы думаете создание потока это быстрая операция?

Comment: попробуйте для интереса заменить ваше `new Thread(...)` на `ForkJoinPool.commonPool().submit( ... )`. Вместо списка тредов у вас будет `List<ForkJoinTask<?>>`, стартовать ничего не нужно, `join()` у них тоже есть. Ваши вычисления будут выполняться в пуле потоков, размером не больше числа ядер, таким образом уйдет постоянная конкуренция за процессорное время.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> почему скорость умножения матриц при параллельном умножении на много
>   медленнее

Из-за `new double[]`-ов в `getRow` и `getColumn`.

```
public void run() {
    int sizeOfMatrix = resultMatrix.length;
    double value = 0;
    for (int k = 0; k < sizeOfMatrix; k++) {
        value += firstMatrix[i][k] * secondMatrix[k][j];
    }
    resultMatrix[i][j] = value;
}
```

*Update*

Судя по тому, что речь идет о **восьми минутах разницы**, матрицы огромные. Не надо создавать столько (`N` в квадрате) потоков.

Создавайте потоков раза в полтора/два больше, чем ядер, и каждому потоку задавайте диапазон индексов строк результата, в которых этот поток будет вычислять значения.

Comment: а где тогда хранить матрицу?

Comment: @ДмитрийЛитвин Где хотите. Не распределяйте память на массивы, содержащие значения из строк и столбцов.

Comment: а как тогда  умножать матрицу на матрицу? по блокам?